# Confused about .Net application settings frameworks

Tags: c#, wpf, application-settings

Being fairly new to the .Net world, I am getting very confused about where and how to store my application settings in a WPF app.

I keep seeing references to `Properties.Settings.Default`, but that does not resolve in my WPF app, and I cannot find what actual classes these are in order to find which assembly to pull in. Is this a WinForms only technique?

I have also found `ConfigurationSettings`, which appears to be deprecated, and `ConfigurationManager`, `AppSettings`, `ApplicationSettings`, and `Settings`! I'm sure many of these work together but I'm having real trouble sorting out what belongs together, and what is old, or irrelevant to WPF.

Can anyone spell out the basic options for a newbie?

Comment: Properties.Settings.Default is a variable defined in the code file that generates Settings.Settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprised that no-one able to answer this, so I have done some more digging and will document my findings here in case anyone else is as confused as me:

- **`ConfigurationSettings`** is dead. (<= .Net 1.1). It used to expose a set of name/value pairs via `AppSettings` member.
- **`ConfigurationManager`** is the replacement (> .Net 2). It lives in `System.Configuration.dll`, and is the basis of all new configuration stuff. It is a static class so can be accessed anywhere. It also exposes a set of name/value pairs called `AppSettings`, presumably for backwards compatibility.
- **`AppSettings`** is not type safe, it's literally pairs of strings.
- **`ApplicationSettings`** seems to refer to `ApplicationSettingsBase`, which is a class used as a base for newer style type safe settings. Subclasses contain members that map to a setting. `ConfigurationManager`is still used to manage / serialise these.
- **`Settings`** is a tool generated static subclass of the above that is generated by adding a "Settings File" to your project, which allows design time editing of the settings. It gets generated into the Properties namespace of your project, hence can be accessed via **`Properties.Settings`** anywhere in your app. Although WinForms is mentioned throughout the docs, it appears to be useable from WPF too.

If you don't want to use a settings file, ConfigurationManager can also be used directly using your own custom classes. Some comprehensive links for an overview of use are:

[Unraveling the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)

[Decoding the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)

[Cracking the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)

All these settings appear to get serialsied to app.config file, although I've seen references to separate Applicationsettings files so I may be wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

If there's not a lot of settings to save, why not use Windows registry?
[File System and the Registry (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzb96fk.aspx)

There's nothing magical about `ConfigurationManager` etc. you could just use your own settings object and serialize/deserialize it to, and from XML.

Refer to the [Application class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.aspx) to learn what the application data path is.

As for `Properties.Settings.Default` not resolving in your application, `Solution Explorer` -> your project -> `Add` -> `New Item` -> `Settings File`. This will autogenerate the `Properties.Settings` class, allowing you to edit your application settings in design time. Then you will be able to call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`

Comment: I can happily roll it myself to registry or file, but I though I would save myself some code given apparent existing mechanisms.

Comment: Also the Application class is a WinForms class. My app is WPF

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer it's in the WinForms namespace yes, but you can use it in a WPF application with no problem; I do. Similarly, I write in C# and I use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` class - no problem either. It's just namespaces.